# Contrast 2 arrays in php

Tags: php

So I have 2 arrays in PHP, one with the following structure:

$tables

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 206
            [number] => 150
            [capacity] => 4
            [booking_code] => qhJEHcWnzty062DD
            [reservation_date] => 2020-07-09 01:00:00
            [start_time] => 12:30:00.000000
            [end_time] => 14:15:00.000000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 206
            [number] => 150
            [capacity] => 4
            [booking_code] => ym9dP1aZtFstP3WM
            [reservation_date] => 2020-07-22 01:00:00
            [start_time] => 20:00:00.000000
            [end_time] => 21:45:00.000000
        )

)
```

The second array is the same structure but with a lot more rows which is $tablesWithDate.

I want to create a function that returns an array which is basically the second one, minus the data in the first one. So `array1 = (1, 2, 3 , 4); array2 = (1, 4)` I'd like the result to be `array3 = (2, 3)`.

Here is my attempt thus far

```
function availableTables($tables, $tablesWithDate) {
        $tablesReturn = array();

        for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($tables); $i++) {
          if($tables[$i]['table_no'] != $tablesWithDate[$i]['number']) {
            $tablesReturn[] = array(
              "table_no" => $tables[$i]['table_no']
            );
          }
        }
        return $tablesReturn;
      }

      $tables = getAllTables($connection);
      $tablesWithDate = getTablesWithBookingOnDate($connection, $date);
      $tablesReturn = availableTables($tables, $tablesWithDate);

      return $tablesReturn;
```

I'm getting like 200+ errors of `undefined offset 2, 3 4, etc`

EDIT

```
function availableTables($tables, $tablesWithDate) {
        $tablesReturn = array();

        foreach($tables as $table) {
          foreach($tablesWithDate as $twd) {
             if($table['table_no'] != $twd['number']){
               $tablesReturn[] = array(
                 "table_no" => $table['table_no'],
                 "capacity" => $table['capacity']
               );
             }
          }
        }
        return $tablesReturn;
      }
```

Comment: Have you tried something like [array_diff()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)?

Comment: if I do `$tablesReturn = array_diff($tables, $tablesWithDate);` I get an array to string conversion error

Comment: I tried return and print_r() It gives the error on that line which is strange

Comment: Could it be that because they are an array of arrays?

Comment: Do you need a full comparison of the sub-level array data here - or can you go by the `id` value alone? If the latter, then I’d extract the ID values from the first array using `array_column`, and then use `array_filter` on the second one with that list of IDs.

Comment: I need to compare it by sub level array data, that's what I was trying to do in my function

Comment: I have edited the question, I nearly have the code doing what I wan't but now it gives me a duplicate of every row i need